# ASP.net MVC project: should I update jQuery version?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When you create an `ASP.net MVC` project in Visual Studio (even the newest version, VS 2017) it includes a very old version of `jQuery`, version `1.10.2` to be precise.

The question is: can I safely upgrade to the latest `3.x` versions? Or is there a good reason why the ASP.net MVC template includes `1.x` by default?

NOTE: I haven't written any code yet, so there will be no problem on my part, I'm just wondering if it will break something in ASP.net/MVC and the default libs that ship with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's Completely Okay to change the Version your self with the version you want it wont affect the Asp.net at all i did it its 100% safe. 
you can update:

```
 pm> Update-Package jQuery
```

**Update**
Any Front-end Based function Wont affect The asp.net in anyway 
 just in case you written some code before it may affect your Views(Html) only not anything else at all its a Clint side script anyway

Comment: You haven't written anything its 100% safe

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating new project it simply uses existing project template. The template was created long time ago and I do think it is not updated since then. That is the reason `jQuery` version is `1.10.2` as this version was available at the time template was created. In general `jQuery` is there because [Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation](http://Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation) NuGet package. This package is dependent on `jQuery >= 1.8` and `jQuery.Validation >= 1.8.0.1`.

You might want to take a look at [jQuery upgrade guides](https://jquery.com/?s=upgrade%20guide), if you want to be 100% sure, but I don't see any other connection to jQuery in new project and it is safe to update it. I have never had problems updating every NuGet package to latest right from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't write any code in the application, Yes you can include new jquery version.